# Excel Conditional Format from lookup

Tags: excel, excel-dna

I have the following scenario:

Sheet1 has an excel table that refreshes from the database.
The table has a unique key column.

Sheet2 has static information, let us say a subset of rows of Sheet1 that have been user entered and where they match a row from the excel table on Sheet1.

Let us assume we refresh the table on Sheet1 and for a particular key (row) a value in the table changes, now my static entry for the same key on Sheet2 no longer matches in one of the columns.

I would like to highlight the cell in the row on Sheet2 for that mis-match.

I have access to excel-dna and can create custom functions etc as required.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a little bit 'light' on what is where so my offer not tailored to OP's exact requirements however this might be a good thing if more widely useful.

I am assuming key values are in ColumnA and values to be updated/compared are in ColumnB (both sheets). Select ColumnB of Sheet2 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=B1<>INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colour Fill (highlight) of your choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.